# Is there a way to change layout on Login ? - Sass / ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, sass

I'm building a ReactJS app . And i wonder ( maybe this will sound stupid or not ) , but is there a way on login to detect a user ID and when once detected to change the layout of the app  ( the colors ) . I have done some research , but didn't get a clear view of it . So any help will be welcome . Thank you

Comment: before login or after login?

Comment: @Ashish after you login . The main idea is to have a blank app at first and when a user is logged in to change the layout

Comment: The short answer is yes... Conditional rendering... If you want further help see [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: @PandaMastr you can do it using any theme provider. get basic theme configuration after login and store it somewhere. and call them for theme configuration.